# Apache 406 Not Acceptable when specifying Accept: header

Tags: php, apache

I've tried to find a solution for this myself but solutions to other 406 problems haven't helped me.

I have enabled PHP and the Apache web server on my Mac.  I have found that if I pass a request (POST or GET) with the Accept: header set, then it fails with a 406 error:

```
$ curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost/test/tester
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /test/tester could not be found on this server.</p>
Available variants:
<ul>
<li><a href="tester.php">tester.php</a> , type application/x-httpd-php</li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

However, if I exclude the "Accept: application/json" the request executes without error.

I tried adding this test/tester.var (in the same dir as test/tester.php):

```
URI: tester

Content-type: application/json
URI: tester.php
```

My intention was to direct Apache to handle request with "Accept: application/json" by executing tester.php.  But it hasn't helped me (I also added 'AddHandler type-map .var' under 'IfModule mime_module' inside my httpd.conf file and restarted the server).

'mod_security' doesn't appear to be configured, but I added the following .htaccess to my test/ directory anyways:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

These are solutions that I found on the net by none have worked for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out a fix!  As I suspected, *mod_security* had nothing to do with my problem.

Here are the changes that I made to */etc/apache2/httpd.conf*:

1. Enabled type maps in  by uncommenting "AddHandler type-map var" line
   in the "IfModule mime_module" section.
2. Added the following two lines to the "IfModule mime_module" section:

   ```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
   MultiviewsMatch Handlers Filters
   ```

In my PHP source directory, I created a *tester.var* in the same directory as *tester.php* with the contents:

```
    Content-type: application/json
    URI: tester.php
```

It's all good now.

Comment: what does it cause the problem itself? I'm having the same issue when making an ajax POST request through Chrome in mac but working fine with the rest of OS and web browsers