# Mod_security 406 with a '~' in the URL

Tags: php

I get a 406 Not Acceptable error while having a URL similar to this:

```
www.example.com/search/find?q=YSBkZXJwIGZyb20gZGVycA~
```

and it seems to be due to the singular `~` character. I have to `base64_encode()` it, using this function:

```
function base64_url_encode($string = null) {
    return strtr(base64_encode($string), '+/=', '-_~');
}
```

Because the normal base64 encode generates an un-parseable URL.

I've had a look around and came across this answer: [PHP/Apache Error:406 Not Acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20198941/2518525)

Which says to disable Mod_Security with:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

I know I'll have to probably find a different rewrite for the function above, but how could I fix this as to not receive the error again, if there is any way?

Comment: Use another character, like the dot or something. Exclamation points come to my head (pun intended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing `=` characters with `~`, just remove them entirely. [This is a common approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), and will not prevent values from being decoded.

Comment: Beautiful. Was just about to update the question asking if I could remove the padding. Thanks.